# Dynamic columns are adding in angular ui-grid but column values are not displaying

Tags: angular, angular-ui-grid

I am trying to add a new column dynamically in `ui-grid` which is already appearing on the page. For which i used the code below to add object in the `columnDefs` array :

```
$scope.$on('SHOW_PROPERTY_SHEET_COLUMNS', (event, propertyObj:any) => {
    //this.selectDetailsPropertyColumn(propertyObj);
    let newColumn = {};
    let selProp = propertyObj.selectedProperty;
    let columnsLength = vm.gridApi.grid.options.columnDefs.length;
    let fieldName = `regular[0].${selProp.name}`;
    console.log('fieldName', fieldName);
    newColumn = { 
        displayName: selProp.displayName, 
        name: selProp.name, 
        field: selProp.name, 
        width: 100, 
        hidden:0,
        cellTemplate: propertyCellTpl(selProp.name), 
        visible: true, 
        enableColumnResizing: true
    };

    gridApi.grid.options.columnDefs.splice(parseInt(columnsLength-1), 0, newColumn);
    vm.summaryColumns.push(newColumn);
    vm.gridApi.grid.refresh();
});
```

And for the cellTemplate we are using the below function :

```
function propertyCellTpl(field){
    console.log('propertyCellTpl', field);
    return {{row.entity.regular[0].${field}}}>;
}
```

Above code adding the new column perfectly to the grid but not showing the values for their respective column. Can anyone help in regarding this issue which i am facing.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your function to this. The return value should be an HTML template, so it would be a string value. For instance, you could have `cellTemplate: '<span>hi</span>'`.

```
function propertyCellTpl(field){
    console.log('propertyCellTpl', field);
    return '{{row.entity.regular[0].field}}'>;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying brian, i tried the code as you suggested but it still showing the blank column and on debugging the element in firebug it looks like its not using the cellTemplate

Comment: What if you just do `cellTemplate: "<span>testdata</span>"`?

Comment: yes i tried that but for that also its not showing the value for the newly added column.

Comment: You'll have to create a demo to explain what you are doing better. Generally a simple value in cellTemplate would show up in that cell, so something larger is wrong.